# Can't connect to Bigtable from a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a standalone application that works fine with Bigtable when creating a connection like this:

```
Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(PROJECT_ID, INSTANCE_ID)
```

and using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev78-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev11-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
    <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.2</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.33.Fork26</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm converting it now to a Spring Boot web application, so I had to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I haven't changed anything else at all, **just added these 5 lines** and now I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_1.BigtableConnection
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:72)
    at poc.google.cloud.BigtableTest.testHelloWorld(BigtableTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:85)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL via netty-tcnative were properly configured.
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.<init>(BigtableSession.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:104)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_1.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:48)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: I don't think I ever tested tcnative Fork26 and have had luck with Fork19; I don't know if that's the issue.  I've run into various classpath relating to tcnative originating from ordering issues with jetty and tomcat environments, for example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/876 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421958/google-cloud-bigtable-java-client-tcnative-errors.  I couldn't debug the problems

Comment: I tried `1.1.33.Fork19` with no luck. For now I know that it has something to do with the `org.apache.tomcat.embed:spring-boot-starter-tomcat` transitive dependency brought by the `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: The 'tc' in tcnative stands for tomcat.  There's some kind of conflict when tcnative and tomcat are both available.  One possibly alternative is to use alpn_boot, although the gRPC highly recommends against doing so... https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-with-jdk-jetty-alpnnpn

Comment: I found a simple workaround as explained in my answer, in case it helps you in future developments of the Bigtable java client library. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries used to connect to Bigtable seem to have some kind of conflict with the Tomcat libraries used by Spring Boot by default.

**Use Jetty instead of Tomcat as a workaround.**

`com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java` went missing after this transition, so don't forget to add it too

This is how you replace Tomcat for Jetty in Spring Boot:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Excluding spring-boot-starter-tomcat from Spring Boot and adding spring-boot-starter-jetty
made protobuf-java disappear although it's still needed -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```